# Замена слова sed

Tags: linux, sed

Появилась задача заменить с помощью редактора sed 1 на 2/2, но при замене командой

```
echo "abc 1 def" | sed "s/1/2/2/"
```

Появляется ошибка

```
sed: -e expression #8, char 6: unknown option to `s'
```

Подскажите, как можно сделать это с помощью sed, или же предложите альтернативный вариант.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378997

Comment: Я чётко написал, что нельзя использовать иные разделители, так как значение для замены подставляется из переменной.

Comment: для того, чтобы избежать совпадения разделителя, используемого в команде substitute программы sed с динамически подставляемыми в качестве аргументов команде произвольными строками, можно [поступить очень по-разному](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4844854/4827341)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Решил, заменив разделитель на ; так как строка, содержащая ; не может подаваться на вход в моём случае.
Команда приняла вид

```
echo "abc 1 def" | sed "s;1;2/2;"
```

Comment: _использовать другие разделители вместо / не получится, так как на месте 2/2 может быть всё, что угодно_  - Ваш вопрос и ответ противоречат друг другу

Comment: Изменил, спасибо.

Comment: `;` использовать в качестве разделителя — это подкладывать себе грабли под ноги.